# RAID 5 Windows 10 Host OS Running CentOS-Linux in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, centos-7, raid-5

This is my first time using a Virtual Machine so please forgive my ignorance.

My computer is running Windows 10 and then in VirtualBox I'm running CentOS. I have 3 new 1TB HDDs. I want to run the 3 drives in a RAID 5 configuration and then use the RAID 5 in CentOS. If I setup a RAID 5 in Windows 10 (the host OS) will CentOS recognize the RAID 5?

Or do I need to setup the RAID 5 in my VM? If I'm running RAID 5 in my VM can I also access those drives directly through my host OS (Windows 10)?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my own question is YES; if you setup a RAID 5 in Windows 10 that drive will be available for use in CentOS running in VirtualBox. For example, lets say I install three new drives (lets call them drives 2, 3, and 4) and I configure them into a RAID 5, calling it Local Disk (B: ). If I then create a new virtual machine in VirtualBox (for running CentOS), I can select that new Local Disk (B: ) as my storage location. There is no special configuration required for VirtualBox/CentOS to use the RAID 5 drive.

Comment: Correct, VirtualBox is an application.  It will see whatever Windows presents to it. Keep in mind that CentOS has no idea that it's on a RAID5 volume, it only sees the inside of the VDI container presented by VB.